# Testing the methods present in different packages

Tags: go

While writing test cases I found 2 problems:

1. There are 3 test files out of which `one_test.go` and `two_test.go` can be added to `server_suites_test.go` and it runs fine. But the functions of `three_point_one_test.go` cannot be added into `server_suites_test.go` because `_test.go` cannot be imported.
2. `one_test.go` and `two_test.go` use gRPC client object which is created by `server_test.go`. Actually, `server_test.go` creates a gRPC server and a client and this client is used by the other test cases. Currently `three_point_one_test.go` cannot access this client. So to solve this issue I'm creating client every time this test is run.

Project Structure(incomplete BTW!)

```
> tree /f
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is 1C92-17A5
C:.
└───data
    │   one.go
    │   one_test.go
    │   two.go
    │   two_test.go
    │   server.go
    │   server_suites_test.go
    │   server_test.go
    │   
    └───three
            three_point_one.go
            three_point_one_test.go
```

server_suites_test.go

```
package data

import (
    "testing"
    "someproj/three"
)

func TesOne(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("One", testOne) //from one_test.go
}

func TestTwo(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("Two", testTwo) //from two_test.go
}

// Below code cannot be compiled -START
func TestThreePointOne(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("ThreePointOne", three.TestThreePointOne) //cannot import this function
}
// Below code cannot be compiled -END
```

Is there any way to add other tests present in children packages into the test suite?

Comment: If you are testing unexported functions, you must test it in the same package. Normal rules apply, testing is not special in this regard.

Comment: @Flimzy I tried that way too. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to add other tests present in children packages into the test suite?

No.

Tests are not part of the package. As you can import only whole packages and the tests are not part of it you simply cannot. And stop thinking about "child packages": There are no such things. All packages are equal and their filesystem location does not matter (except internal and vendor).